# how to add pdfs from R to an openoffice presentation?

Tags: pdf, r, openoffice-impress

I am using R to produce plots in pdf format, which I believe contain SVG information inside. I would like to use the same pdf files for my OpenOffice presentation (LibreOffice 3.3.4, OOO330m19 (Build:401)). Is there any way to add these directly without having to do much format conversion?

Comment: I personally would not go that way. If you want to add a plot in a presentation go for a png. Chances are that PPT will destroy your plot for other users, or some page resize will scale wrongly text and lines. If you want to insert into LO for editing then I truly recommend to edit that with inkscape or similar, and save as png. Having said that, this is an interesting knowledge to have in the toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the "PDF Importer" extension installed in OpenOffice / LibreOffice, you can directly open PDF files as graphics documents - from there, you can copy and paste vector graphics and text into an Impress document.

This works with R plots but some of the point symbols don't always come across correctly!